# Resources are not immediately released on closing app after calling method from Win32_OperatingSystem

Tags: c#

I've been working on an application for, primarily, learning purposes. Right now, the app will ping a remote PC in our enterprise and then, if it's determined online, pull bits of information to display. The next part I'm trying to do is send commands to the remote PC such as telling it to reboot.

I was able to code up a method that would do that using the Reboot method from Win32_OperatingSystem. One thing I've noticed however is once I use that method and then shut down the application, Visual Studio's debug mode will continue running and showing memory in use for close to a minute.

As I stated earlier, I'm doing a lot of this for learning purposes and I'm in the deep end of the pool with some of these bits of code. The app closed immediately and released resources previous to this so I feel I'm not doing something correctly. Any assistance would be appreciated.

This is the current method I have for restarting a remote workstation.

```
private void RestartWorkstation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher($@"\\{HostName}\root\cimv2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");

    foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
    {
        mo.InvokeMethod("Reboot", null);
        MessageBox.Show($"Rebooting {HostName}");
    }

    searcher.Dispose();            
}
```

Comment: `mo` should be disposed also. And put a `using` instead of calling `.Dispose()` directly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried that suggestion but it still seems to hang before releasing resources. I tested by letting the application run a bit after using that method and when I closed it, it only ran for ~8 additional seconds. I have the target PC I'm testing against and can verify the reboot command is firing off without delay. I'm assuming there is some connection to the remote PC that has to run it's course.

Comment: Temporarily disable the installed security software and try again.